# django-rest-framework edit data after validation

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a few fields on my serializer and I have overridden the `validate` method on serializer to do some object-level validation.

The problem is after validation, I need to edit the final data before passing it to create function. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # Some lengthy validation with attrs['a'] and attrs['b'] and attrs['c']

        # if validated
        attrs['a'] = updated_a
        attrs['b'] = updated_b
        attrs['c'] = updated_c
        return attrs
```

Update has to be done after the validation. I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this.

I could subclass the `Field` and provide custom `to_internal` and `to_representation` but I don't know how to do validation beforehand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`validate` method is not the best place for this. Especially when now in DRF3 you have `create` method available for you.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    data = validated_data.copy()
    data['a'] = 'updated value'
    return super(MySerializer, self).create(**data)
```

Comment: i don't think you need to do `**data` when calling super, it might cause an error, it should be just `data`.

Comment: @mariodev I got it working without copying the dict. What is the use of validated_data.copy() ? Is there something going to mess up if copy is not called ?